# Abort an event and start another event

Tags: apache-flex, simultaneous-calls

in flex application i have a button and two functions in action script...
wat i wan is when i click the button it has to call a function and Abort 
and call another function  simultaneously....I hope You guys caught wat i wanna convey...thanxx:-)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "calling a function, abort, call another function"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="{appCreationComplete()}"
    >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function appCreationComplete():void
            {
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandlerA);
                btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandlerB);

            }

            private function clickHandlerA(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("clickHandlerA");
            }

            private function clickHandlerB(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("clickHandlerB");
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button id="btn" label="Click me"/>
</mx:Application>
```

In this sample On **Applocation CreationComplete** we are binding two **event handler**
to **button**

Hopes that helps